# Bracket Balancing

Tags: java, stack

can someone help me with this code it is not working with this test case{(([])[])[]]}.

```
package myProject;
import java.util.*;


public class bracketBalancing {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter String");
    String s=sc.next();
    Stack<Character> stack=new Stack<Character>();
    if(s.length()==0)
    System.out.println("string is empty");
    else {
      for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
      char ch=s.charAt(i);
      
      if(ch=='('||ch=='{'||ch=='['){
         stack.push(ch);
      }
      else if(ch==')'&& stack.peek()=='('){
          stack.pop();
      }
      else if(ch=='}'&& stack.peek()=='{'){
          stack.pop();
      }
      else if(ch==']'&& stack.peek()=='['){
          stack.pop();
      }
    
      }
    }
      if(stack.empty()){
          System.out.println("YES");
      }
      else{
      System.out.println("No");
      }
      sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the else condition to print `No` if you are neither able to `push` not `pop`. Because in that condition it means you have some additional closing brackets which will lead to unbalanced.

**Code:**

```
if (s.length() == 0) { 
      System.out.println("string is empty");
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);

        if (ch == '(' || ch == '{' || ch == '[') {
          stack.push(ch);
        } else if (ch == ')' && stack.peek() == '(') {
          stack.pop();
        } else if (ch == '}' && stack.peek() == '{') {
          stack.pop();
        } else if (ch == ']' && stack.peek() == '[') {
          stack.pop();
        } else {
          System.out.println("No");
          stack = null;
          break;
        }

      }
    }
    if(stack != null) {
      if (stack.empty()) {
        System.out.println("YES");
      } else {
        System.out.println("No");
      }
    }
```